# View MV test results after finishing a test

Tags: content-testing

A question popped up yesterday when I was discussing MV testing with a client.

When starting a MV test, there is the option to automatically select a winner after either the result is statistically significant (90/95/99% options) or when the duration of the test has passed.

In case you want to manually select a winner, you need to access the test results and then pick a winner based on all kinds of information (clicks, conversions).

However, in this case the client wants Sitecore to pick the winner. But some time after Sitecore picks a winner, the client wants to view the test results dialog to see the test details.

There seems to be no way to access the test results dialog AFTER an MV test is completed.

Is this a bug or just missing functionality? In my opinion historical MV test results should stay accessible...

We're on 8.2 initial currently by the way.

Comment: did you ever find a way to do this? I'm facing the same problem and can't find any way to view historical test results.

Comment: No I haven't. Frankly, I think it's an ommission in the current version of the platform...

Answer (score 3):

In case somebody else still faces the same issue the answer is No.

Unfortunately, the old Sitecore versions don't allow to see the detailed test results about the completed tests. Only starting from [Sitecore version 9.1.0](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/91/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_91_Initial_Release.aspx) released in November 2018 this functionality became available:

> ​You can now see detailed test results about completed tests. To see
> the details, in the Experience Optimization application, in the
> Historical tests list, click on an item.

See the full release notes for version 9.1.0 [here](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/91/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2091%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes).